# I get a "Incorrect syntax near ')'"

Tags: sql-server, select

I wrote this query in a stored procedure and call it from C#. It works fine.

```
WITH SelectedRows AS
(
     SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY InnerDataTable.DepotCode ASC) AS RowNo, 
         InnerDataTable.* 
     FROM
         (SELECT DISTINCT 
              Date, No, Person.Title AS PersonTitle, Person.Name AS PersonName, 
              (... some other columns from tables ...)
          FROM 
              SellInvoice
          JOIN 
              SellInvoiceDetail AS Detail ON Detail.SellInvoiceGuid = SellInvoice.Guid
          JOIN 
              Depot ON Depot.Guid = SellInvoice.DepotGuid
          JOIN 
              Item ON Item.Guid = Detail.ItemGuid
          ( ... and something else... )) AS InnerDataTable  
     WHERE 
         InnerDataTable.Company = '391891BA-DCC9-4B76-9588-9C97E0C2071A' 
         AND InnerDataTable.Branch = 'A2C9055A-7DDD-41AF-9A2F-DFC42D6C2B14'
)
```

But when I test it in SQL Server Management Studio, execution fails and it's showing an error:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

It's refers to last line.. What's that error..?

Comment: There's no way this runs from C#. The query is incomplete. It's one big CTE *without* any code to use it. It's just a `WITH SelectedRows AS (..)`, without an actual query that uses it

Comment: You might want to post the full code and avoid the "{and somthing else...}".

Comment: Put a semicolon before `WITH`

Comment: This is part of a StoredProcedure that return a table true in program running.But I need to test it in sql server.So separate this part

Comment: You will 100% want to test the stored procedure and not just a small section.

Comment: @Majid821 does the stored procedure include a SELECT after the final parenthesis, but you didn't include that part when you tried to separate it?

Comment: @DenisRubashkin the semicolon is a statement terminator not a beginninator. Often you see ctes start with a semicolon because it requires the previous statement is terminated with one. It is a strange syntactical thing that somehow caught on and has many people confused as to why it is there.

Comment: @SeanLange, thanks, I know it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the actual SELECT from your CTE. For more guidance on how to use CTEs (common table expressions), see [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
WITH SelectedRows AS
(
     SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY InnerDataTable.DepotCode ASC) AS RowNo, 
         InnerDataTable.* 
     FROM
         (SELECT DISTINCT 
              Date, No, Person.Title AS PersonTitle, Person.Name AS PersonName, 
              (... some other columns from tables ...)
          FROM 
              SellInvoice
          JOIN 
              SellInvoiceDetail AS Detail ON Detail.SellInvoiceGuid = SellInvoice.Guid
          JOIN 
              Depot ON Depot.Guid = SellInvoice.DepotGuid
          JOIN 
              Item ON Item.Guid = Detail.ItemGuid
          ( ... and something else... )) AS InnerDataTable  
     WHERE 
         InnerDataTable.Company = '391891BA-DCC9-4B76-9588-9C97E0C2071A' 
         AND InnerDataTable.Branch = 'A2C9055A-7DDD-41AF-9A2F-DFC42D6C2B14'
)
SELECT * -- Added
FROM SelectedRows -- Added
```

Maybe you just didn't include this in your query above, but it seems like a pretty solid reason for SQL Server to return `Incorrect syntax near ')'` on the last line.

Comment: Yes.Thanks.the Error is gone..!! It's run successfully.. but not return somthings

Comment: Most likely it's been filtered out by your inner joins or the where clause. I won't be able to help with that part.